# How can I look up words in a cell and add multiple labels accordingly without duplicates?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to label data rows with pre-defined locations. I am not sure if it is possible with Excel functions, or if a script is required.

The data comes from a free text input field and sometimes contains locations that I am specifically looking for. I then want to add labels to a cell if the input contains one of my locations. Those should be separated by semicolons and not contain duplicates.

Let me give you two examples:

**Input cells**

These are the two example inputs that I want to search for locations so that I can add labels.

| # | input text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tulum, Madrid and Rome |
| 2 | I am looking for an offer in Berlin and the Alps or Vienna |

**Labels**

I now have a long list of locations and associated labels which I am looking for:

| location | label |
| --- | --- |
| Austria | Vienna |
| Austria | Alps |
| Germany | Berlin |
| Italy | Rome |
| Mexico | Tulum |
| Spain | Madrid |

The original list is quite extensive and around 80 labels long.

Now I want to add the locations as labels in one cell behind the input without duplicates. #2 would be a duplicate with Austria twice, I only need it once. If this is the make-or-break, duplicates might also be possible.

The output should look something like this:

**Output**

| # | input text | labels |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tulum, Madrid and Rome | Mexico; Spain; Italy |
| 2 | I am looking for an offer in Berlin and the Alps or Vienna | Germany; Austria |

Now, is there a way to do this via Excel (Google Sheet) Functions or do I need to write an Apps Script to add the labels?

I tried to solve it with a lookup but as far as I know, that can only give me one of the labels and not multiple…

I appreciate any ideas or hints! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: The 1st thing to think about is to pick either Excel or GS as your go-to application. They are not the same neither are their functions or scripts. It's possible with both applications btw, and if you go with Excel, please include your version of it.

Comment: I encourage you to share a sample spreadsheet that is set up as close to your real spreadsheet as possible as far as sheet names, data and output locations, etc. Otherwise, the volunteers here would need to enter your data into their own spreadsheet before even beginning to work on a solution; and afterward, you'd have to do a fair amount of translating proposed solutions to your actual sheet. It's always most efficient and effective if those here can work on actual data in a sheet. If you do share such a link, be sure to set the Share permissions to "Anyone with the link" and "Editor."

Comment: Noted, thanks. However, I fixed the problem by matching each of the locations in separate columns and later joining them using TEXTJOIN().